# Nested mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

How to change the `theo` environment in that way, that a inner `mdframed` will not inherit the style of `theo`?

```
\documentclass[parskip=false,english,11pt]{ltxmdf}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\newcounter{examplecount}
\setcounter{examplecount}{0}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{}

\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
 \stepcounter{theo}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
        {\strut Aufgabe~\thetheo};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
     frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
        {\strut Exercise~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
   }%
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=red!20,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
             frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}

   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
   }{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Header]
Outerframe
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!20,roundcorner=1pt]
Innerframe
\end{mdframed}
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219376/hereditary-properties-with-nested-frames-mdframed-and-tikz

Comment: `%% This documentclass isn't maintanened or efficient for writing` The class by now uses obsolete packages. Please listen to the comment at the beginning of the file and use a proper class like `scrartcl` or `scrreprt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a style separately and apply it to the inner box like

```
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{frametitle={},innertopmargin=5pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,}
```

And then

```
\begin{mdframed}[style=style2,backgroundcolor=gray!20,roundcorner=1pt]
Innerframe
\end{mdframed}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=false,english,11pt]{ltxmdf}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\mdfdefinestyle{style1}{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=red!20,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
             frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{frametitle={},innertopmargin=5pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,}


\newcounter{examplecount}
\setcounter{examplecount}{0}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{}

\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
 \stepcounter{theo}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
        {\strut Aufgabe~\thetheo};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
     frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
        {\strut Exercise~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
   }%
   \begin{mdframed}[style=style1]\relax%
   }{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Header]
Outerframe
\begin{mdframed}[style=style2,backgroundcolor=gray!20,roundcorner=1pt]
Innerframe
\end{mdframed}
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx, an other question comes up, how to shift the frametitle (strutbox) vertical or horizontal? And this Header node should start and and with brackets, which are connected to the outline?

Comment: @user3206010 It is a node so use `shift` or `yshift` or `xshift` in the options.

Comment: That was also my first thought but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. It turns out all you need is to add `default` as the first option before all the rest for the inner mdframed like this:

```
\begin{mdframed}[default,backgroundcolor=gray!20,roundcorner=1pt]
Innerframe
\end{mdframed}
```

The documentation mentions `default` but doesn't mention that you can add other options after that. Apparently options are applied one after another.