# Reset local options in nested mdframed

Tags: mdframed, framed

Is there a way to reset the style options within an `mdframed` environment so that nested `mdframed` environments use the default options automatically?

### MWE

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red] 
        \centering Foo
        \begin{mdframed}
            \centering Bar
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the inner `mdframed` environment to use the default options.
I've tried:

1. Saving `\mdfdefinestyle{default}{}` in the preamble and then using `[style=default]` for the inner frame
2. Using `\mdfset{}` after the beginning the first `mdframed` environment
3. Of course, manually setting `[linecolor=black]` works, but for more complicated instances (i.e. more custom options), I'd rather have it done automatically

Comment: Related: [Hereditary properties with nested frames (mdframed and tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219376/134144)